# IIS SMTP and TLS 1.2

Tags: ssl, iis, smtp

Is it possible for SMTP on IIS to use TLS 1.2?  We are using Windows Server 2012 R2.  According to PCI-DSS requirements, we should be migrating all TLS connections to version 1.2.  I am not referring to the websites in IIS themselves, but the SMTP service.  While using IISCrypto, I limited TLS to 1.2, and it caused our SMTP with TLS connections to fail.  It does not work with version 1.1 either.  Only TLS 1.0 seems to work.

I have not been able to find any definitive answers regarding SMTP and TLS 1.2.  I am open to suggestions, but please keep in mind that budget is a concern.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you using the SMTP service for? It's hard to offer suggestions, or know why it might break with TLS 1.2 if we don't know what you are using it for.

Comment: The iis SMTP is extremely limited, you should use postfix or exchange or an email API solution like mailgun

Comment: @Appleoddity, we are using it to send outbound mail.  I'm not sure what else is to be answered there.

Comment: @JacobEvans, Thank you for the answer.  I feared it was such an answer. We'll do some research to find a cost-effective solution that has high rate limits.

Comment: Look at AWS SES.

Comment: Postfix in docker :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @JacobEvans comment, it looks like it would be best to use something other than IIS SMTP.